# How to replace or delete a specific character in PySpark

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

i'm looking for some help. Im loading some tables in aws using pypark, and when looking the results shows this:

```
+-----------+--------+------+-------------+
|       Name|LastName|Gender|        Birth|
+-----------+--------+------+-------------+
|     Javier|    ;Leo|     n|;M;1999-09-09|
+-----------+--------+------+-------------+
```

And obviusly that's isn't the result i want, i need the correct format without the ";"

```
+-----------+--------+------+-------------+
|       Name|LastName|Gender|        Birth|
+-----------+--------+------+-------------+
|     Javier|    Leon|     M|   1999-09-09|
+-----------+--------+------+-------------+
```

I'm reading the file like this:

```
input_df = spark.read.csv(tables_map[k], header=True, sep=";", encoding="iso-8859-1")
```

but for some reason the sep attribute doesn't work.
So I was looking if anyone knows the way to remove the ";". I appreciate your time and thank you!

Note: sorry if i wrote something wrong, english is not my mother language

Comment: It would help if you provide some sample data as currently we can only guess

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that you will never encounter ';' that value in any functional way in your data, you can use this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = input_df.withColumn('LastName', F.regexp_replace('LastName', '', ';'))
```

[regexp_replace docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace.html)